# How can I code a loop that compares every element of an unordered_set with all the others, using iterators in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, unordered-map, unordered-set

I have an unordered_set and I need to pick each element and compare it with all the others.

Notes:

1. If A and B are compared, I don't need to compare B and A.
2. My unordered_set is the value of an unordered_map, for which the key is a pair.

I tried the following:

```
unordered_map <pair<int, int>, unordered_set <int>, boost::hash<std::pair<int,int>>> gridMap;
unordered_map <int, rigidBody*> objectsMap;


    auto gridMapIt = gridMap.begin();
    while (gridMapIt != gridMap.end()) // loop the whole gridMap
    {
        auto setItOut = gridMapIt->second.begin();
        while (setItOut != gridMapIt->second.end()) // loop each element of the set
        {
            auto setItIn = gridMapIt->second.begin();
            while (setItIn != gridMapIt->second.end()) // versus each other element
            {
                //compare and do stuff

                ++setItIn;
            }

            checked.insert({ objectsMap[*setItOut]->getID(), objectsMap[*setItIn]->getID() });
            checked.insert({ objectsMap[*setItIn]->getID(), objectsMap[*setItOut]->getID() });

            ++setItOut;
        }

        ++gridMapIt;
    }
```

The error I am getting is "Expression: cannot dereference end list iterator". If I remove or comment the innermost while loop, it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `*setItIn` after the loop is invalid. At that point you have an iterator that points *past* the last element. That's what the error is telling you.

If you change from `while` to `for` you can use the scoping rules to stop yourself from dereferencing invalid iterators.

Rather than populate `checked`, you can start the inner loop from the next element, rather than the first.

```
for (auto & gridElem : gridMap) {
    for (auto setItOut = gridElem.second.begin(), setEnd = gridElem.second.end(); setItOut != setEnd; ++setItOut) {
        for (auto setItIn = std::next(setItOut); setItIn != setEnd; ++setItIn) {
            //compare and do stuff
        }
        // setItIn not visible here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you; I was trying also to figure out how to pick the "next" element to optimize it and you already helped with that also. Really appreciated.